# Setting up Project For Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx, github

I am completing Quick start Salesforce DX project- 
"setting up on local machine" Step

while doing this when i copied the command to clone the github repository

I recieve this error (SEE IMAGE). Can anyone help me how i can resolve it. Please note i have dont 1 or 2 other badges from Saleforce DX and I am still trying to get hold of Salesforce DX.

[image]

Need help with resolving this error. Much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have git installed on your computer. Here's a link to the installation steps: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: Much appreciated bro